# Make a program installer for an ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, installation

I need help in making a program installer for my ASP.Net Web Application Project. I am a bit confused because doesn't a website NOT need an installer? If it does, what kind of installer? and how do I do it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish your web application using "Publish Web" wizard.

Right click on your web project, and select "Publish" menu. in the "Publish Web" wizard you can select your publish option, the one that may help you is "Web Deployment Package".

More information:

- [How to: Create a Web Deployment Package in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Deploying Web Applications in Enterprise Scenarios using Visual Studio 2010](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/deploying-web-applications-in-enterprise-scenarios/deploying-web-applications-in-enterprise-scenarios)

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: @TamLandas You are welcome:)

Comment: @TamLandas You can read the links that I provided, and I'll be happy if I can help you:)

Comment: @TamLandas I don't know why someone down votes such a question and such an asnwer without  making any comment. If you find the answer useful, you can kindly accept it as answer to be more useful for other users in the future :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to StackOverflow. Still getting used to how things work around here. But thanks for pointing that out. :D